# Is tomcat suitable for a high load spring websocket (not stomp) app?

Tags: spring, tomcat, netty, spring-websocket, undertow

We are developing a spring websocket (spring boot starter websocket) (not stomp). Currently we use default HTTP server (embedded tomcat)

My question is: Is tomcat suitable for websocket, assume that we cannot scale up the app, the connections are huge (millions of socket connections) and long term, and the ram, CPU is not much powerful (just like a normal PC/laptop)?

If not, is undertow suitable? (Please explain why (not))

If still not, may I switch to webflux and use netty?

I ask this question because I read that tomcat use thread per request model, so I assume that it will create a thread per websocket connection and it will flood my resource very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat and netty (for example) use radically different programming models. Your application may more naturally work with one or the other, but you can't really do both at the same time: you have to pick one and go with it. If your application is already written, then you've already made that choice. Undertow looks like it supports both models, but you still have to choose one (model) and that will dictate which server software is possible to use.

If you need millions of socket connections, your operating system is likely to be the limiting factor and not Tomcat.

Also, if you want to run your "millions of socket connections" on a single "normal PC/laptop" then you just aren't being realistic. If those connections require very little processing power, then okay maybe, but really to support millions of simultaneous connections you will need many many servers, load-balancer(s), etc. regardless of the software that you intend to host your application.

***Update***

I forgot to address one of your statements in your question:

> I read that Tomcat uses a thread-per-request model, so I assume that it will create a thread per Websocket connection and it will [overwhelm my server]

Wobsocket is, by definition, an asynchronous communication scheme. Tomcat will not allocate a permanent thread for each Websocket connection. Instead, a shared pool of threads handles all I/O operations among all open Websocket connections.

Tomcat only uses a thread-per-request model for servlet-based request-processing. This is mandated by the Servlet Specification and all other servlet containers will do the same.

Comment: so which server is best for my case?

Comment: So far your use case has been roughly described as "I need a server that scales". Most servers will scale just fine, and I believe I have answered your question as stated ("Is Tomcat suitable...?"). The answer is "Yes". You will need to provide a *lot* more information if you want recommendations on technology. If you are asking for a *recommendation*, this site specifically requests that you [do not ask such questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource).